# Can we configure modules to build in Angular?

Tags: angular, webpack, package.json, multi-module

I have an Angular application which has different modules such as login module, Payment module, Dashboard module, List module and I want to configure the angular application in such a way that I can configure modules to build while doing `ng build --prod`.

What will be the best way to achieve this? I should be able to specify modules to add for build.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't build specific modules, instead you can use **Lazy loading** to optimize your application,  lazy loading will split your javascript bundle into smaller chunks for modules that get loaded incrementally only when a user wants , and that will not load all your modules in one time.

Your lasy loaded modules will not be downloaded if the user doesn't navigate to them.

https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules